# Node.js - https.get() and JSON.parse() crash the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have uploaded a test application.

Unfortunately, the server crashes.

This is the code snippet that causes the server to crash:

```
https.get(`https://www.instagram.com/${username}/?__a=1`, resp => {
            resp.on('data', chunk => data.push(chunk));
            resp.on('end', () => {
                var json = JSON.parse(data.join(''));
                done(json.graphql.user);
            });
        });
```

This is the error message:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
 at IncomingMessage.resp.on (/app/app/routes.js:108:33)
 at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
 at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
State changed from up to crashed.
```

The code crashes on `JSON.parse()` but I think there is some error with the `https.get()` line. Unfortunately, i cannot understand what's wrong and i am researching this for days.

EDIT: What is even weirder, is that sometimes this code works as normal, other times it crashes the server.
I mean for a specific username it works, but then again for that same username it does not.

Comment: you should never trust a third party response, so try catch your parsing. Probably, your data is not JSON-parsable :)

Comment: But the tricky part is that sometimes this code works. I shoudl edit that in the question. Is there a way to make it JSON parsable?

Comment: just consider that the server decides NOT to send a json. e.g a 404 if the user does not exist, a 500 if they are down, a 403 for some restricted user.... you can be a cowboy and check the response status, and try to parse on 20x  without try catch, but well if you like crashes it is up to you

Comment: I re-edited the question. The weird thing about this error is that  for a specific username it works, but then again for that same username it does not. And when it works, and when the server crashes, it is random.

Comment: once again most probable thing is you don't get a consistent response from the server. So check your status code, write your try/catch and add some logs to understand what's happening

Comment: Thanks. The way to do that is to wrap all that code inside a try?

Comment: wrap the code involving the third party response: ```try{var json... return done(json.graphql...)}catch(e){return done('some error occured')}```

Comment: Thanks! From your response an idead popped Should i put it in a try/catch block, and when it fails, then try again until it works?

Answer (score 2):

From what i see, this is caused by doing these requests too much.
You can check if it is a valid response by simply doing `data.join("") === ""` - works for everything, except invalid users - for that, you can check if `data.join("").startsWith("<!DOCTYPE html>")`

This is because when you are being throttled the response is simply empty, and when the user is invalid it's the HTML content of a website that begins with `<!DOCTYPE html>` and that allows us to check for it easily.

## Checking if the data is valid

```js
if(data.join("") === "" || data.join("").startsWith("<!DOCTYPE html>")) {
    console.log("Invalid data!")
}
```

## Checking if it is an invalid user or you are being throttled

```js
if(data.join("") === "") {
    // throttled
} else if(data.join("").startsWith("<!DOCTYPE html>")) {
    // invalid user
} else {
    // valid data and user
}
```

## *Almost* complete code

```js
https.get(`https://www.instagram.com/${username}/?__a=1`, resp => {
    let data = [];
    resp.on('data', chunk => data.push(chunk));

    resp.on('end', () => {

        if(data.join("") === "") {
            // You are being throttled - handle it
        } else if(data.join("").startsWith("<!DOCTYPE html>")) {
            // The user is invalid - handle it
        } else {
            // Everything is OK
            const json = JSON.parse(data.join(''));
            done(json.graphql.user);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Like i said in the Edited part of the question, some times the code works fine, other times it crashed the server. And when it workds and when it doesn't is unpredictable.

Comment: I got it to happen. My idea is you are requesting it too much - i ran it on a setInterval every 100ms and after about a minute it started erroring out.

Comment: No this isn't the case because i don't run this in a loop like you did right now. Some times, the error is the first thing that happens. I am really curious what this is about. Did you logged data.join('')?

Comment: An idead that just popped up from the response on the comments on the other question is to put it in a try/catch block, and when it fails, then try again until it works.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. You can try this solution and check if it fixes all your issues - it does for me.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to test this right now. Where do i put your code snippet? What lines should i replace?

Comment: You should put it in the same scope as where you do `JSON.parse()` and put the parse in an `else {}`.

Comment: But where do i put the  done(json.graphql.user); line?

Comment: Could you please post the whole code as you managed to make it work on your system?

Comment: Thank you so much!! What do you mean though you are being throttled?

Comment: Instagram sees you are requesting a bit too much and they limit it.

Comment: I don't think this is the reason though, because the error is the first thing that happens. Without previous traffic.

Comment: I tried your code but the only result i got where the user is invalid. I don't know why that happens. In the past, sometimes it worked.